# Returning filenames from an origianl dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not quite sure what this means.

for (location, date, caption) in value_dict.items():
       builtins.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
Can anyone help me fix this please?

```
def create_date_dict(image_dict):
'''(dict) -> dict

Given an image dictionary, return a new dictionary
where the key is a date and the value  is a list
of filenames of images taken on that date.

>>> d = {'image1.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Friday']}
>>> date_d = create_date_dict(d)
>>> date_d == {'2017-11-03': ['image1.jpg']}
True
'''
new_d = {}
for (filenames, value_dict) in image_dict.items():
    for (location, date, caption) in value_dict.items():
        new_d[date] = {list(filename)}
return new_d
```

Comment: value_dict is of type 'list'. Lists are iterable by default, no need of '.items()'

Comment: Please indent the code and show how you actually call the function to get that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value_dict` is a list.  Your second `for` loop should look like

```
for location, date, caption in value_dict:
```

to take advantage of iterable unpacking

Edit:

Actually, now that I look at it again, you don't need another loop at all. Just do

```
location, date, caption = value_dict
```

Edit 2:

I'm not sure what's responsible for the new error you're getting.  Try this function, it fixes some other things I noticed in you original

```
from collections import defaultdict

def create_date_dict(image_dict):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for image, (loc, date, cap) in image_dict.items():
         d[date].append(image)
    return d
```

This uses [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which is a handy `dict` subclass from the standard library

Edit 4:

without a `defaultdict`, this would look something like

```
def create_date_dict(image_dict):
    d = {}
    for image, (loc, date, cap) in image_dict.items():
         if date in d:
             d[date].append(image)
         else:
             d[date] = [image]
    return d
```

Comment: Do I need the brackets around location, date and caption?

Comment: Ok, but after I test it, it says lcoation isn't defined for some reason

Comment: How do I define it? by setting up an index for it using a key?

Comment: @bigd You are defining it.  What line is the error on?

Comment: @bigd See my latest edit.  I fixed some other peculiarities I noticed in your code as well

Comment: Just curious, how would we be able to do it without the default dict?

Comment: In the else statement, is it saying that if the image is already there, just leave it as it is?

Comment: @bigd Nope.  If there is already a list in d associated with `date` (`if date in d`), then we append to that list.  Otherwise, we create a list just containing `image` and then associate it with the appropriate `date`.

Comment: Ok, Thanks so much